# How to see if IIS is actually sending requests to ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-6, httphandler

I have setup in the script maps for a site in the IIS metabase a wildcard mapping to ASP.Net for a particular directory within the site.

I have a handler setup in the web.config which should be handling requests for said path and it should never return an actual 404.

I have this configuration in place for another site on the same server which is working perfectly.

For this particular site I am receiving a 404 response for all requests matching the path.  I don't know if I have a problem with the script maps or the web.config or the handler itself.

How can I find out where the problem lays so that I can troubleshoot it better?

Is there a concrete way for me to ascertain if the 404 is being returned by ASP.Net or IIS itself?

I am using IIS 6 on Windows Server 2003 with .Net 3.5 SP1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspecting the 404 response showed that it was not coming from IIS since IIS had a default 404 page and this was returning a 0 byte response.

The error was actually in the handler.